# Hashmap, the values are null

Tags: java, hashmap

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyHashMap<K,V> extends HashMap<K,V> {
    public MyHashMap(K[] keys, V[] values) {
        super();
        // Store the <key,value> pairs to the HashMap object

        HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        map.put("Hydrogen",1);
        map.put("Lithium",3);
        map.put("Sodium",11);
        map.put("Potassium",19);
        map.put("Rubidium",37);

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Done";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Two Arrays
        String[] elements ={"Hydrogen","Lithium","Sodium","Potassium","Rubidium"};
        Integer[] atomicNumbers = {1,3,11,19,37};

        MyHashMap<String,Integer> map = new MyHashMap<String,Integer>   (elements,atomicNumbers);    
        for (int i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("The atomic number of " + elements[i] + " is "+          map.get(elements[i]));
        }

        System.out.println(map.toString());
    }
}
```

The out put is wrong (The atomic number of Hydrogen is **null**), I`m not sure whether  something is wrong when I put the key and value or other mistake in my code. Please help!

Comment: Why are you extending HashMap?

Comment: Why do you override `toString` in such a useless way ?

Comment: Remove the extends HashMap, and just use one in the main method.

Comment: For example: 
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("Hydrogen",1);
map.put(...

Comment: how can I printout the keys and values by calling toString method( System.out.println(map.toString()) ), what should be returned in the method to String? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that `MyHashMap` *is* a `Map`, but you still have to populate the values.  This is accomplished by utilizing the arrays you have declared in `main`.

You don't want to create this object if the size of the arrays are off (or the arrays are `null`); I leave the latter as an exercise for the user.

```
public MyHashMap(K[] keys, V[] values) {
    super();

    if (keys.length != values.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Array lengths are not equivalent!");
    }
    // Store the <key,value> pairs to the HashMap object
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        put(keys[i], values[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, how can I printout the keys and values by calling toString method( System.out.println(map.toString()) ), what should be returned in the method to String? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems:

1. In your constructor, you're storing things in a local map that you don't keep. *Your* map, the `MyHashMap` instance, has nothing in it.

   Remove the `map` variable from your constructor, and use `this` instead, e.g.:

   ```
    this.put(...);
   ```
2. Secondly, you're not using the `keys` and `values` you pass into your constructor in the constructor. You're just using a a series of hardcoded statements in the constructor itself. So this both doesn't make sense logically, and also won't compile, because there's no guarantee (at that stage) that `this.put` can be applied to `String, Integer` (even though that's what you do later). If you use the values from `keys` and `values`, though, as they're typed `K` and `V`, it will work.

E.g., fixing both, remove the series of hardcoded lines in the constructor (along with the `map`) and use a loop over `keys` and `values`:

```
if (keys.length != values.length) {
    // Throw an exception or similar
}
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i) {
    this.put(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

Comment: One more question, how can I printout the keys and values by calling toString method( System.out.println(map.toString()) ), what should be returned in the method to String? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the entries in the `map` object and this object's scope is limited to the `MyHashMap` constructor

Try this:

```
public MyHashMap(K[] keys, V[] values) {
    if (keys.length == values.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            this.put(keys[i], values[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question, how can I printout the keys and values by calling toString method( System.out.println(map.toString()) ), what should be returned in the method to String? Thank you!

Comment: @CJDEG if you don't override the `toString(...)` in your class it will use the super class' `toString(...)` method so just remove the `toString(...)` method from your class and they should be printed correctly.